# How to resolve ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34?

Tags: python

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34 (from versions: 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.14.51, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.2.52, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66, 4.7.0.68, 4.7.0.72)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34

I want to install
opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34
opencv-python==4.2.0.34

which version of Python is best?

Comment: You can download old packages directly on pypi - https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/4.2.0.34/#files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I want to install opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34 opencv-python==4.2.0.34" - okay, and **exactly how did you try** to do this? **Why do you need** this specific version, and where do you think this version list is coming from? What is your existing understanding of how Pip resolves dependencies? (Or are you using Poetry, or something else?)

Comment: Avoid asking which "is best". Your question could get closed as opinion-based. It also depends a lot on your environment, e.g., what libraries you want to use and what Python versions these support.

Answer (score 0):

opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34 was published on April 4, 2020.
On April 4, 2020, the current version of Python was 3.8.2, and the current version of PIP - was 20.0.2.
So you can try to use this.
It's always a good idea to check the documentation of the specific libraries or applications you work with to see which Python versions they support.